# ionic 4 cordova android build error - transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build the Android app and getting this output error:

```
BUILD FAILED in 39s
/Users/myuser/dev/myapp/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
D8: Program type already present: com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
  Program type already present: com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat
  Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
```

Things I tried according internet search results:

- `cordova clean` + `cordova build`
- remove android platform and add it again
- clone repository in another place and build it from scratch

So the same error keeps happening.

Here is my `package.json` file for reference:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic-native/app-rate": "^5.19.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^5.17.1",
    "@ionic-native/badge": "^5.17.1",
    "@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "^5.17.1",
    "@ionic-native/call-number": "^5.19.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^5.17.1",
    "@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^5.17.1",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "^5.19.1",
    "@ionic-native/firebase": "^5.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase-x": "^5.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.17.1",
    "@ionic-native/google-maps": "^5.0.0-beta.27",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^5.19.1",
    "@ionic-native/launch-navigator": "^5.19.1",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^5.17.1",
    "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "^5.17.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.17.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.17.1",
    "@ionic-native/unique-device-id": "^5.19.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.7.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "call-number": "^1.0.1",
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": "^3.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-actionsheet": "^2.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx": "^1.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-apprate": "^1.5.0",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "^0.8.8",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^6.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-firebasex": "^7.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": "^2.6.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "^2.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "^3.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "~2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid": "^1.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "~1.3.3",
    "cordova-support-android-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "cordova-support-google-services": "^1.3.2",
    "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^5.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "ionicons": "git://github.com/ionic-team/ionicons.git#3.0",
    "ios-sim": "^8.0.2",
    "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": "0.0.2",
    "ngx-mask-ionic": "^1.1.2",
    "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "^8.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": "^5.0.4",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
      "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION": "28.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-badge": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-firebasex": {
        "FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED": "true",
        "FIREBASE_PERFORMANCE_COLLECTION_ENABLED": "true",
        "FIREBASE_CRASHLYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED": "true",
        "ANDROID_ICON_ACCENT": "#FF00FFFF",
        "ANDROID_PLAY_SERVICES_TAGMANAGER_VERSION": "17.0.0",
        "ANDROID_FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_VERSION": "17.2.1",
        "ANDROID_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_VERSION": "20.0.0",
        "ANDROID_FIREBASE_CONFIG_VERSION": "19.0.3",
        "ANDROID_FIREBASE_PERF_VERSION": "19.0.1",
        "ANDROID_FIREBASE_AUTH_VERSION": "19.1.0",
        "ANDROID_CRASHLYTICS_VERSION": "2.10.1",
        "ANDROID_CRASHLYTICS_NDK_VERSION": "2.1.1"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": {},
      "cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-apprate": {},
      "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": {
        "GOOGLE_API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID": "AIzaSyDb5ggUt5U1vXF2RSVHvtecnX-xv36Lays",
        "OKHTTP_VERSION": "3.12.0",
        "LOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "Veja estabelecimentos mais próximos de você com dinheiro de volta"
      },
      "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": {},
      "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": {
        "API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID": "AIzaSyDb5ggUt5U1vXF2RSVHvtecnX-xv36Lays",
        "API_KEY_FOR_IOS": "AIzaSyDb5ggUt5U1vXF2RSVHvtecnX-xv36Lays",
        "PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "15.0.1",
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+",
        "LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE_DESCRIPTION": "Somente utilizamos a sua localização quando o app estiver aberto",
        "LOCATION_ALWAYS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app wants to get your location always, even this app runs in background."
      },
      "call-number": {},
      "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
        "APP_ID": "573564436804950",
        "APP_NAME": "myapp",
        "FACEBOOK_HYBRID_APP_EVENTS": "true",
        "FACEBOOK_ANDROID_SDK_VERSION": "5.5.2"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-androidx": {},
      "cordova-plugin-compat": {},
      "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION": "27.+"
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Possible conflicting plugins (from my package.json)**

A few answers tells about conflicting plugins managing android/firebase versions. So maybe using all these libs/plugins can be the problem?

npm

- @ionic-native/firebase-x
- cordova-android-support-gradle-release
- cordova-plugin-androidx
- cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter
- cordova-plugin-firebasex
- cordova-support-android-plugin

cordova plugins

- cordova-plugin-firebasex
- cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter
- cordova-plugin-androidx
- cordova-plugin-compat
- cordova-android-support-gradle-release

---

What else can I try to solve that? It's been 2 days spent on this issue :(

Answer (score 1):

Can u try this steps

```
cd platforms/android
gradlew clean
cd ..
cd ..
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

Comment: same error but another class: `Program type already present: com.google.zxing.Binarizer`

Comment: try remove android platform then run build code (ionic cordova build android --prod --release)

Comment: I have the same problem, tries a lot of things, trying your solution then gradlew' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Comment: can u see result after run 'gradle -v' @GaliloGalilo

Comment: I am working on ionic (I dont use gradle), but solved by updating all plugns one by one, then  minimum sdk. Thank u